# Embed Google maps with Microsoft Power BI

Tags: google-maps, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am a power BI user. I want to embed Google Maps in Power BI so as to have a flexibility like:

Lat and Long

I want them to get plotted on the Google map and when I click a location on google map, it should give me the option to put up the destination by fixing the clicked location as current location so that I can find out the distance between both the locations.

Please respond!

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is a Microsoft product and does not integrate with Google maps.

Power BI can plot data on a Bing map with lat/long. However, it doesn't sound like you want to plot data, but rather you want an interactive distance calculator. For that, I would not recommend Power BI at all.

Comment: Kindly whats recommended for distance calculator reporting tool, as I have the same task